# How to recognize which UIPickerView received event when they share a Data Source

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I have 2 `UIPickerView`s with different datasource arrays. My problem is that I can't figure out how to display both datasources to my 2 picker views.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return firstArray[row]
}
```

How can I return both of my datasources to my picker views? The logical solution is to recognize if the first picker view is tapped, use `firstArray` as datasource, and if the second picker view is tapped, use another array.

Guide me on which properties and methods to use please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to declare both `UIPickerView`s as `@IBOutlet` stored properties at the top of the class (be sure to link these up properly in StoryBoard):

```
class MyVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var picker1: UIPickerView?
    @IBOutlet weak var picker2: UIPickerView?

    /* set up the delegates ... */

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        switch pickerView { 
        case picker1: return firstArray[row]
        case picker2: return secondArray[row]
        default: /* print an error or assertion failure */ return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it works, the arrays are showing, but when I select the second picker, its throwing an error: array index is out of range.

Comment: I updated the numberofrowsincomponent as well, it works perfectly now, thanks!